# Custom install path for Nuget Packages in VS with Content like JS files

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I was thinking of using Nuget to pull in some JS libraries and the only issue I have is I use a custom path for my JS files. Is there a way to tell NUget in VS to put the package in a set path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this isn't supported today, though there's been many discussions about this here http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: Has this been added yet?  I find myself moving and renaming folders after a nuget install and then doing it all over again whenever there's an update. Not a deal killer, but would be nice if it could be controlled.